# I couldn't find any link for Sum row data in groups into columns MSSQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I tried below query

```
SELECT 
    DATEPART(hh, CreatedDate) as 'hour',
    DATEPART(DW, CreatedDate) as 'week', 
    COUNT(*) as 'Entries created'
FROM LogTable
WHERE CreatedDate>= '2020-01-01' and UpdatedDate <= '2020-10-31'
GROUP BY DATEPART(DW, CreatedDate),DATEPART(hh, CreatedDate) 
Order by DATEPART(hh, CreatedDate);
```

which gave me below result

[image]

I want result Like

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT [hour]
      ,[1] AS [Monday]
      ,[2] AS [Tuesday]
      ,[3] AS [Wendesday]
      ,[4] AS [Thursday]
      ,[5] AS [Friday]
      ,[6] AS [Saturday]
      ,[7] AS [Sunday]
      ,ISNULL([1],0) +ISNULL([2],0) + ISNULL([3],0) + ISNULL([4],0) + ISNULL([5],0) + ISNULL([6],0) + ISNULL([7],0) AS [Grand total]
FROM
(
    SELECT 
    DATEPART(hh, CreatedDate) as 'hour',
    DATEPART(DW, CreatedDate) as 'week', 
    COUNT(*) as 'Entries created'
    FROM LogTable
    WHERE CreatedDate>= '2020-01-01' and CreatedDate <= '2020-10-31'
    GROUP BY DATEPART(DW, CreatedDate),DATEPART(hh, CreatedDate) 
) DS
PIVOT
(
    MAX([Entries created]) FOR [week] IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7])
) PVT;
```